# Multidimensional array declaration fails after update to Eclipse Juno with Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, eclipse-juno, scala-2.10, scala-ide

I recently updated to Eclipse Juno and therefore to Scala 2.10 as well. I had code that worked perfectly before, however, after the update I get a "too many arguments for constructor Array" error for this line:

```
var labyrinth = new Array[Array[Cell]](lines.length, lines.apply(0).length);
```

It should represent a two-dimensional array. I wonder what the problem is, since it's been working before. When I run the project (ignoring the error) it doesn't compile and it gives me a "class not found" exception.

I'm running Eclipse Juno with Scala 2.10 on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating arrays with constructor was [depreacted](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/index.html#scala.Array) since scala `2.8`. You should use `Array.ofDim[Cell](lines.length, lines.apply(0).length)` instead.